# Is there any way to forcefully focus a particular item in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus, android-tv, persist

I am trying to design an Activity in Android for a TV platform, In which i am showing a menu which is basically A RecyclerView , having TextView as Item View of the RecyclerView. There are 8 items in the RecyclerView. It is basically situated at the left side of the screen.

Whenever i try to navigate from the RecyclerView to the other View components and navigate back to RecyclerView the focus goes on any Random item view of the RecyclerView, the focus is chosen based on the nearest item view to the another view component from which we are navigating to RecyclerView.

My question here is, can i forcefully set the focus on a particular item view in the RecyclerView whenever i navigate to the RecyclerView. Also Can anyone suggest a blog or paragraph where deep working or understanding of the RecyclerView is written.?

I have tried using the PersistentFocusWrapper class, but it is somehow not working here. Hence i am looking to create a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll RecyclerView  to any position you want on your activity onResume() put this code :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {   

                recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).

                    }
                }, 50);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but unfortunately i dont want to scroll to the position in onResume of an activity. As i have mentioned in the question , i want to scroll to a position whenever the focus is navigated from recyclerview to any other view component and back to recyclerview.

Comment: you should save position in a variable when recyclerview get clicked and on resume scroll to that position that is in variable

Comment: I am not doing any activity transitions , as i have mentioned in the question ,, i am trying to navigate between two recyclerviews, they are on the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onFocusChangedListener to your RecyclerView and in the onFocusChange callback once the view receives focus you can scroll to the correct position -

Register listener -

```
mRecyclerView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

Handle focus -

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

The hasFocus boolean indicated if the view just got the focus or just lost it